# Date.parse gives me NAN for string date...Wait What?

Tags: javascript, date

So consider the following:

```
Date.parse('August 28th 2016');
NaN
```

Wait what? Whats the proper way to get the Date Time for this so I can do something like:

```
data.sort((a, b) =>
      Date.parse(Object.keys(a)[0]) -
      Date.parse(Object.keys(b)[0]))

Object.keys(a)[0] // => August 28th 2016
```

So ... Whats the proper way again?

Comment: you can't parse a date with that format and you aren't reassigning...

Comment: The proper way would be to get the integers representing the parts of the date and pass them on to `new Date`

Comment: I think **th** is the problem. Try `Date.parse('August 28 2016');`, it works

Comment: `Date.parse('August 28th 2016'.replace('th',''));` works. You need to remove the `st`,`th`,`nd` from your string you are passing. Or do it properly from the source if possible, like @adeneo is pointing out.

Comment: You can't depend on any particular browser to parse non-standard date formats. You need to parse it yourself, or use a date parsing library.

Comment: @JClaspill—maybe in some implementations, but there is no requirement in ECMA-262 for any implementation to correctly parse anything other than a limited subset of ISO 8601 formats.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to make working with dates more easy. Your task can be accomplished with:

```js
var dates = [moment('August 28th 2016' ,'MMMM Do YYYY'),moment('August 22nd 2016' ,'MMMM Do YYYY'),moment('August 12th 2016' ,'MMMM Do YYYY')];

dates.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.isAfter(b);
});

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Or maybe nicer -- if your object's keys are strings now:

```js
var dates = ['August 28th 2016','August 22nd 2016','August 12th 2016'];

dates.sort(function(a,b) {
  return moment(a,'MMMM Do YYYY').isAfter(moment(b,'MMMM Do YYYY'));
});

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```